# "the night sounds" vs. "night sounds"

Tags: articles

I've gone through [Cambridge Dictionary grammar tutorial on "the"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the)

[From VOA](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/under-below-beneath-and-underneath/4785334.html)

> We sat under the stars and listened to **the night sounds**.

In a **complete situation**, should those night sounds be mentioned first, and then use "the"? For example,

> Christopher and I were best friends, both of us **love night sounds**. Most of the time in our childhood, we met at the top of the hill near my house. We sat under the stars and listened to **the night sounds**.

Comment: I don't think that there's anything special about the noun *night sounds.* Depending on context, `We love cake.` `We ate the cake.` `We ate cake.` `We ate a cake.` could all be correct. I think that a complete understanding of the rules surrounding *the* will answer your question.

Comment: @Max Thank you. I totally agree that all your example are correct. What I am asking for help on is the situations, would you please make up some situations where one of those suites?

Comment: I would suggest reading some of the top answers in the [definite-article] tag here and seeing if any confusion remains. Then you will be able to ask a more specific question than this.